# Stop All SQL Agent Server Jobs with Specific Job Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Very occasionally, I will get a SQL Server Agent job executing an SSIS Package that stalls, preventing future runs of the job. I don't always catch this quickly which means a job can be stalled for several days. Is there a way to stop all SQL Server Agent jobs that start with a specific name?

Currently, I am using the below query to stop a job if it is running. However, I would like to be able to apply this to any job where the name is like 'SSIS-%' without having to write it out for every SSIS job or modifying for future SSIS jobs. Then I would setup a job to run once day to find and stop any stalled jobs.

```
Declare @Running int
Declare @SSISPackage varchar(50); 

set @SSISPackage = 'SSIS-Job_name';

/*Check if Job currently is running*/
SELECT 
    @running = CASE
                WHEN sa.start_execution_date IS NULL or (sa.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sa.stop_execution_date IS NOT NULL) THEN 0
                WHEN sa.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL AND sa.stop_execution_date IS NULL THEN 1
                END 
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity sa ON sj.job_id = sa.job_id
WHERE sj.name = @SSISPackage;         

/*Stop Running Job*/
if @Running = 1
    BEGIN
        exec msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job @SSISPackage
    END;
```

Is this possible? Is there a better way to approach?

Comment: Why not solve the underlying problem and fix the matter of the "stalling"? This is clearly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. I should have specified, I will go back and fix whatever issues is causing the stall, but I think this kind of job is a valuable fail safe.

Comment: I agree with Larnu. Fix the stalling SSIS package.